# Define JPA relation with condition on another relation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following (legacy) DB schema that I want to model in JPA/Hibernate:

```
TABLE A {
  id integer
  b_foo string
  c_bar string
}
TABLE B {
  id integer
  foo string
}
TABLE C {
  id integer
  bar string
  b_id number
}
```

The relations are:

- A ManyToOne B
- A ManyToOne C
- C ManyToOne B

In SQL, I could do the following:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B
  ON B.foo = A.b_foo
JOIN C
  ON C.bar = A.c_bar
  AND C.b_id = B.id
```

The issue is that I need `b.id` in the JOIN to get the `C` relation, and `@JoinColumn`'s and `@JoinFormula`'s `referenceColumnName` only allow "simple" column names.

This is what I have tried so far:

```java
@Entity
class A {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "b_foo", referencedColumnName = "foo")
  private B b;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "c_bar", referencedColumnName = "bar")),
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "(SELECT B.id FROM B WHERE b.foo = b_foo)", referencedColumnName = "b_id"))
  })
  private C c;
}

@Entity
class B {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  @Column(name = "foo")
  private String foo;
}

@Entity
class C {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  @Column(name = "bar")
  private String bar;
}
```

While this works, it's considerably less efficient than the raw SQL join.

I could also do:

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "c_bar", referencedColumn = "bar")
private C c;
```

and then just add `WHERE c.b_id = b.id` in my queries. That would perform significantly better, but I couldn't find a way to do that in one general/global place so I don't have to remember to add it to every query. The `@Where` annotation doesn't allow querying relations AFAIK.

I am currency using hibernate 6.2.7.

Is there any other way to implement these relations in an *efficient and global* manner?